# What else keeps putting the wrong project into the solution?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been working with this VB.NET ASP.NET solution all day. It has 12 projects in it. One of them, named PJATools, was being referenced from the wrong folder. I tried, several times, to fix it withing Visual Studio, but it never worked. Finally, I decided I'd better edit the solution file. (There were several other similar problems resulting in a few hundred errors. Editing the .sln file and making it point to the correct project within the solution, fixed all of those.) However, removing the PJATools.vbproj from the .sln file, then adding the existing PJATools.vbproj immediately makes VS point to the wrong folder, with the wrong .vbproj file.

I have tried deleting all of the .DLLs generated by previous builds. I have tried doing a Build Clean. No matter what I do, it always points to the wrong folder with the wrong .vbproj, the instant I add the correct .vbproj in the correct folder to the project.

There must be other files in a VS solution or project, which can change where VS thinks a project in a solution, is to reside. The only thing I can think of is the .sln file and other .vbproj files which might reference PJATools. I've checked all. If they reference PJATools at all, they point to the correct folder and .vbproj file. So, it must be something else. But what?

I'm working with VS 2019. .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: There's a folder called `.vs` in the same location as the .sln file. This holds all sorts of data like directory locations and solution/project settings. (It's a hidden folder, so you'll need to display those.) You can try deleting that, then re-adding the problematic project to your solution. But be aware that you may delete some other settings - but hopefully not too many.

Comment: Deleting that folder *won't* break your projects, though. It's a sort of 'cache' used by VS to keep track of things between sessions. If you delete it, a new one will be created next time you open the .sln file. I've wiped it out, on a few occasions, to clear stuff that persists like only Microsoft stuff can persist.

Comment: Can you expand on how a project is referenced "from the wrong folder"?  Are you saying that you _expect_ to have multiple copies of a file named "PJATools.vbproj" in multiple folders, but only use one of them in your solution? Or does VS somehow switch the folder path for this project, but the .vbproj doesn't exist at that path? (Best to update the question with this info, rather than adding more comments.)

Comment: Sorry Sean, that I wasn't clearer. Here's the folder structure. There's 3 folders which are siblings: DotNetLibraries, DotNetProjects & Reporting. DotNetProjects has the .sln file & 8 projects each in a folder. DotNetLibraries has 2 folders w/ a .vbproj in each. Reporting has the same structure. Those 4 projects are a part of the solution, but not under DotNetProjects. VS2019 does build, but I want to put all into source control for build, which doesn't work since those 4 projects aren't in source control. Early yesterday I copied those 4 projects under DotNetProjects. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Then within VS2019 I'd remove the projects that are in DotNetLibraries & Reporting. After removing those 4 projects, I'd add the existing 4 projects back into .sln, looking for them under DotNetProjects. The moment I added any of the 4 projects under the DotNetProjects, VS2019 would instantly see them being under either DotNetLibraries or Reporting! Then I spent hours editing the .sln and .vbproj files to get the folder structure correct. Made no difference; VS2019 always saw those 4 projects under DotNetLibraries or Reporting.

Comment: @AdrianMole, deleting the `.vs` folder did the trick! Finally, after several hours, now VS 2019 sees all the folders being under DotNetProjects! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I should convert my comments into a formal answer? I assumed it was already given, somewhere on Stack Overflow. However, I did a fairly extensive search but didn't find any *real* duplicates.

Comment: @AdrianMole, unfortunately although deleting `.vs` has helped a lot, there are still issues. I've found that when adding the 12 projects back into the solution, it is still looking at the DotNetLibraries and Reporting folders to find a few of the projects, instead of DotNetProjects! SO FRUSTRATING! Somewhere either VS2019 is retaining that information or perhaps TFS is. Any ideas?